# Saving multiple pages for raster maps

Tags: r, dictionary, raster

I need to save multiple pages of raster maps. I use "trellis.device" to save them, but it failed. See the below example for details.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r1[] <- sample(c(0,1),100,replace=TRUE)

r2 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r2[] <- sample(c(0,1),100,replace=TRUE)

sp1 <- stack(r1,r2)

library(rasterVis)

## save as pdf with two pages (It works in this way)
trellis.device(pdf, file="Test.pdf")
levelplot(sp1,col.regions=c("grey","darkgreen"))
levelplot(sp1,col.regions=c("grey","darkgreen"))
dev.off()

## save as pdf (It doesn't work when including a for loop)
trellis.device(pdf, file="Test.pdf")
for (i in 1:2){
levelplot(sp1,col.regions=c("grey","darkgreen"))}
dev.off()
```

Comment: You need instead to do `print(levelplot(sp1,col.regions=c("grey","darkgreen")))`

Answer (score 3):

This is listed in the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f). By default R does not print values returned inside of loops the way it does when you enter a single value at the command prompt. you need to explicitly print the plot.

```
trellis.device(pdf, file="Test.pdf")
for (i in 1:2){
print(levelplot(sp1,col.regions=c("grey","darkgreen")))}
dev.off()
```